# How to set scale in WKWebview?

Tags: javascript, html, swift, cocoa, wkwebview

I´m trying to modify the scale of a page load in a `WKWebView`. It is working as far as I´m looking in the html. But the actual scale in the WKWebview doesn´t change.

Here´s how I inject the script:

```
let script =
       "var viewport = document.querySelector(\"meta[name=viewport]\");" +
       "viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4, user-scalable=0');" +

let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script,
                                      injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
                                      forMainFrameOnly: true)
userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
```

Print the html:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML", completionHandler: { (innerHTML, error) in
            print(innerHTML)
        })
```

HTML result in console:

```
Optional(<!--<![endif]--><head>
        <title>Bitcoin (BTC)  $2391.84 (1.85%) | CoinMarketCap</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4, user-scalable=0">        
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="EDc1reqlQ-zAgeRrrgAxRXNK-Zs9JgpE9a0wdaoSO9A">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

I´m asking myself if this is the right approach. I also tried: `let script = document.body.style.zoom = '0.8';` and `let script = document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.8)';` which is both working in terms of scale, but using this method, the timeperiod slider in [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/) highchart loses its functionality. Any kind of new ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES">` to your HTML file.

(I added right after  but not sure if you can add it anywhere)

In my case I have html files for privacy in my Xcode project. I added that javascript code right below the  and it did the trick for me.

It works as if you used `scalePageToFit` in UIWebView.

Hope it helps.